# quiero hacer esta linea de código en python y no se como

Tags: python

quiero hacer esta linea de código en python pero no como hacer la raiz de un numero en un for, se que normalmente se hace numero**0.5 pero no se como hacerlo para llevarlo a un for
`for a in range (2, raíz(numero))`

Comment: Hola Pablo, no se si entiendo el problema, si se trata de iterar desde 2 hasta raiz cuadrada de numero el único problema es que `range` solo acepta enteros, p.e `for a in range (2, int(numero**0.5))`. Ambos argumentos han de ser enteros, la conversión depende de si quieres redondear, aplicar la función suelo, techo, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Una posible solución es parsear el resultado de 'raíz(numero)', que por defecto es float, a int.

Ejemplo:

```
#In
numero = 25
for a in range(2, int(numero**0.5)):
    print(a)


#Out
2
3
4
```

Lo que tienes que tener en cuenta con esto es que si el resultado de raiz(numero) tiene parte decimal, al parsearlo a entero, solo se queda con la parte entera.